# Black Screen on Macbook Pro 6,2 After Installing 12.04LTS - Tried Everything Already

Tags: 12.04, grub2, macosx, macbook-pro, refit

I am tri-booting Mac OS 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard), Windows 8, and Ubuntu. I installed via a USB drive. The install and the LiveCD trial went flawlessly, and I can boot into GRUB. However, as soon as I press Enter on the installed Ubuntu, it brings me to a black screen. I left it there for about an hour, and it was still black. No words or anything. I tried 13.04, and that worked, but it wasn't 100% compatible, so I much prefer the LTS. So far, I have tried:

- Failsafe Graphics
- Reinstalling
- Putting nomodeset and no splash in GRUB
- The custom [Mac LiveCD](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/release/) (wouldn't boot from the USB drive)
- Adjusting my brightness (believe it or not, that's a common solution)
- Switching graphics mode through GRUB (got a garbled mess, but I think Unity was running in there somewhere because my backlit keyboard lit up)
- Entering --quiet splash nomodeset and quiet splash nomodeset (brought me to the splash screen with orange dots, then kicked me back out to a totally black screen)
- Pressing Esc during the splash screen (gave me a bunch of checks, all came back [OK], but kicked me to the black screen again)

Keep in mind, I'm kind of a beginner. I know much more than the average beginner, but I wouldn't call myself intermediate just yet.

One more thing: the black screen I'm getting is NOT backlit, and there is NO blinking cursor. It looks as if I turned the computer off, but the fans are still running and I think the hard drive is still doing something)

Comment: Have you tried booting Ubuntu from the built in boot manager? As your computer is starting up, hold/tap the OPTION key, then select Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah, sadly it's not there. I can really only get to it through rEFIt

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add nomodeset after --quiet splash I have a MacBook Pro 5,2, and this is what I must do.

Boot up and wait for grub, press C, use arrow keys and add the option.

Comment: I tried doing both

--quiet splash nomodeset and 
quiet splash nomodeset

They both brought me to the splash screen with the logo and orange dots, but it kicked me to a black screen after that

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried pressing the ESC Button when the Splash Screen appears? You should see a couple of messages scrolling down.

Check if you can get a Login Shell this way. :)

Also, you can Boot into Run Level one by Editing the GRUB Entry that you are using to boot Linux, and Append 1 to the end of the Line starting with the linux Word

Comment: Pressed Esc at the splash screen. A bunch of text started scrolling (they were almost all checks and they all said "OK"). Sadly, it kicked me out to the black screen. Also, I could not find a line in GRUB that started with the "linux" Word